# Example from Bogachev's book on Extension of measure from algebra to $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading the book of Bogachev "Measure Theory. Vol 1" the following theorem and important remark to this theorem:[image]

[image]

I understood the proof of this theorem completely but I am not able to understand the meaning of this example.

1) What does mean the term "has no signed countably.."?

2) Can anyone explain why it has no signed extension to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and how it follows from (iii)?

3) What is the essence of this example?

Would be very grateful for detailed explanation!

Comment: "signed countably additive extension" means an extension that is a signed measure that is countably additive

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there exists such a signed measure $\nu$. Then $\nu$ is nonnegative on $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\nu^{+}\ge\nu^{-}$ on $\mathcal{A}$ and, therefore, $\nu^{+}\ge\nu^{-}$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ (e.g., by Theorem 1.9.3, where you take $\mathcal{E}=\{A\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}):\nu^{+}(A)\ge \nu^{-}(A)\}$). This implies that $\nu$ is nonnegative on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and must coincide with $\mu^{*}$ by uniqueness.

On the other hand, the example with $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,X\}$ shows that signed extensions to $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ do exist.

Comment: Let me ask you the question: sorry but what is $\nu^+$  and $\nu^-$?

Comment: The positive and negative parts of the Jordan decomposition of $\nu$ from Chapter 3 ($3.1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know the Jordan dexomposition yet. Will return to this question when will be ready. Anyway thanks! I am sure that we will discuss it in the near future.

Comment: @RFZ Then, you possibly need to cover section 1.9 (monotone and $\sigma$-additive classes)...